# Run program with specified library

Tags: centos

Is it possible to specify a path with the library that the program should use instead of searching system variables?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options here. The most common would be

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/custom/path:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./yourprogram
```

Second, slightly more powerful is

```
LD_PRELOAD=/custom/path/lib.so ./yourprogram
```

The first just puts your path first in the search list. The second loads your library before any other libraries are loaded. Neither one takes the default search path out completely. Probably good unless you are replacing all dynamically loaded libraries.

If you are compiling your own program you have a few more options. You can link statically (either completely or with just a `.a` of your lib) or you can set a run-time search path. Options to do this may vary depending on your compiler.

Adding a comment:

If you are concerned with appending a blank path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` you can use

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/custom_path${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH} ./myprogram
```

Getting a little complex for a one-off command but it is safer overall. Thanks to Stephen Kitt for pointing out the issue.

Comment: The first command do not **ADD** path, it replace library path!

Comment: @RomeoNinov You're right and I edited the answer. I so rarely have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set that I forget to add instead of replace.

Comment: there are also things like `patchelf` that can set specific things within a binary, but that's more invasive

Comment: Take care with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/custom/path:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` starts of empty or unset, that results in adding the current directory to the library path.

Answer (score 1):

If you preload a library, the dynamic linker will use that to bind symbols before looking for other libraries:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/library.so program
```

You can check this beforehand with `ldd`:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/library.so ldd program
```

If this is successful, you’ll see `/path/to/library.so` in the output instead of the system library requested by `program`.

Comment: Thank for your help.